# How to implement NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification handler as completion block in Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I need to do operation on managed objects that are already saved and owns final `objectIDs`. Is it an easy way to do it via completion handler?

```
Utility.managedObjectContext().performBlockAndWait({
let success = Utility.managedObjectContext().save(nil)


    //do some logic but only after save was completed, and managedObject owns final objectIDs
})
```

Comment: Why a notification? The `save()` method is synchronous. The permanent object IDs are  assigned on return from the save.

Comment: right, now I see, thanks